# resize image responsive in <ul> tag using foundation 5 framework

Tags: html, wordpress, zurb-foundation-5

Hi i have this foundation 5 library in my wordpress site. I already have the foundation 5 library in my wordpress files. The classes in foundation 5 works good. But my problem is when i added a `<ul>` tag inside a `<div>` which has a class of `medium-4 large-4 columns text-center` ive noticed that my images wont work when i resize my browser the images will not take effect of the responsiveness but when i remove the `<ul>` tag and use the class `medium-4 large-4 columns text-center` the images will take responsiveness when i resize my broswer. My problem is i want that my images will take responsiveness when i resize my browser. How will i able to do this? Can someone help me figured this thing out?Any help is muchly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the [block-grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html) ?

Comment: Could you put your wrong code ?